# XSLT: Loop over a range of elements, page by page

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to transform this XML to create pages of  tags as my XSLT output, let's say 3 per page so I end up with something like this:

I can do everything I need except group them into pages.

```
INPUT XML:
<root>
   <element>a</element>
   <element>b</element>
   <element>c</element>
   <element>e</element>
   <element>f</element>
   <element>g</element>
   <element>h</element>
   <element>i</element>
</root>

XSLT RESULT XML:
<root>
   <page num="1">
      <element>a</element>
      <element>b</element>
      <element>c</element>
   </page>
   <page num="2">
      <element>d</element>
      <element>e</element>
      <element>f</element>
   </page>
   <page num="3">
      <element>g</element>
      <element>h</element>
   </page>
</root>
```

I tried `position() mod X`, but the order seems important because I'm trying to break the xml 10 separate files, and using `exsl:document` this way causes it to overwrite the file each time, only keeping the last element:

```
<exsl:document href="chunk-{position() mod 10}.xml">
```

It seems like I need to loop over them in sequence (1-3, then 4-6, then 7-8).

Note: I'm using xsltproc on linux, so it supports EXSL but not XSLT2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="element[position() mod 3 = 1]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element">
    <page num="{position()}">
      <xsl:copy-of select=". | following-sibling::element[position() &lt; 3]" />
    </page>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's a simple example, but it should be enough to demonstrate the principle.

Comment: XSLT feels like gym for the brain. I get it, thanks so much for a simple, easy to follow example that just works!

Answer (score 2):

You can transform the sample input into the required output as follows:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="block-size" select="3"/>

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="element[(position() - 1) mod $block-size = 0]" mode="page"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element" mode="page">
  <page num="{position()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::element[position() &lt; $block-size]"/>
  </page>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So that stylesheet takes one input document and creates one output document, as your samples indicate.

You also mention `exsl:document` but I am not sure what you want to do with that as your wanted result seems to be a single document. So please show samples of the different documents you want to create if that is part of the requirement.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this was really useful in helping me understand how this all works, and I get it now. I really appreciate  the time you spent on it. I wish I could mark two correct answers!

Comment: I had only mentioned exsl:document because I didn't want to get the "sort by columns" solution I saw in many places, it's a more simplified version of position mod X than you guys gave. I left it out for simplicity, but it works in my code perfectly now.